# ImportError: No module named 'auth'

Tags: django

In the the urls.py I have

```
from django.contrib import auth
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/',include('auth.urls')),
]
```

> ImportError: No module named 'auth'

But the following works

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Why am I not able to former method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `auth.urls`, it aspect that you have an app named `auth` and you installed it in `settings.py`. But you don't have auth app.

But when you use `django.contrib.auth.urls` that means you access Django auth app URLs which already installed. That why it works.

Comment: But I have one doubt, if it is the case, how am i able to use in admin.py -> from django.contrib import admin -> admin.site.register or is it only for urls?.

Comment: only for urls.py